# What are the exact restrictions on night time Eiffel Tower photos?

Tags: legal, regulations, paris, photography

I know that there are some restrictions on night time Eiffel Tower photos, but what exactly is allowed and what is not? Does it make a difference if some persons are on the photo and the tower is only in background? Are there also restrictions on day time photos?

Comment: How do you know that there are restrictions?

Comment: @BartArondson I have read about it in some forums, but the information there is inconsistent

Comment: The mind boggles - first desecrate then copyright and restrict. C'est Incroyable!!! [Numerous boringly similar desecrated images do seem to exist.](http://goo.gl/WMV9N). What you want is the Eiffel Tower at night in NZ -  none of this rubbish of copyright of a public view would exist. (Achieving this "may be difficult" :-) ).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Regarding the eiffel tower:**
[Image rights / the Eiffel Tower brand](http://www.tour-eiffel.fr/en/the-eiffel-tower-image-and-brand/image-rights-the-eiffel-tower-brand.html)
By day, the sun light and the eiffel tower are in public domain, you can take it in picture and publish / try to sell the pictures as you want.
By night, the eiffel tower artistic lighting is under copyright if it's the main subject of the picture.

I think if it's for your little blog among your friends / a little audience, it should be ok (writing the "copyright Tour Eiffel - illuminations Pierre Bideau" is a plus).
If you have a big blog or try to make a commercial use, you must ask (and pay) for the right at the Eiffel Tower company (SETE).

**Regarding someone in a picture:**
[If someone makes a picture of me, who owns the right to it? - photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25511/if-someone-makes-a-picture-of-me-who-owns-the-right-to-it)
[Personality rights - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_rights)
If the person is the main subject and you can recognize them, you have to ask them before to publish.
If they are far away and barely recognizable it's ok.
(There is an exception for public figure during public life.)

Comment: What I mean is Does it makes a difference if I take a photo of friends of mine in front of the tower, or just a photo of the tower

Comment: No, if the tower is still important in the picture i think its rights applies. Adding somebody will not revoke the rights. If you want a picture of the tower by night for yourself and your friends, just take it, nobody will prevent you.

Answer (score 16):

@travelot clearly laid out the most relevant rules but I would like to clarify something and highlight an important distinction: There is – to my knowledge – no general restriction on *taking* pictures of the Eiffel tower (the police might ask you to stop taking pictures, e.g. if you are disturbing traffic and the like but that's something else).

The issues with copyright or personality rights only come up if you want to *publish* these pictures *in France*. To the extent that copyright protection really applies, it does not in any case have any impact on your right to take pictures for your own private use. Publication in another country will be regulated by the local laws and international agreements (I don't really know but I doubt personality rights can generally be enforced abroad, copyright however is covered by international treaties but the details are complex).

Also, would-be right-holders (museums, the SETE, etc.) are generally not to be trusted for information on copyright, they routinely try to claim rights they don't have (e.g. on pictures of old artifacts stored in a museum) and to intimidate people who want to take pictures without any sound legal basis.

Answer (score 1):

The view of the lighted Eiffel Tower is only copyrighted when it has non-standard lighting.  So, when the Eiffel Tower just has yellow lighting, it is not copyrighted but I believe it is under Creative Commons.

This information is coming from a native French friend of mine.

Comment: Regarding the official website [tour-eiffel.fr](http://www.tour-eiffel.fr/en/the-eiffel-tower-image-and-brand/image-rights-the-eiffel-tower-brand.html), i'm afraid your friend is wrong.

Comment: The official website has no legal authority to redefine French law.  The law is that the view of the lighted Eiffel Tower is only copyrighted when it has non-standard lighting.

Answer (score -3):

Travelot is arguably wrong.  If not, there wouldn't be over 300 free photos of the Eiffel Tower here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Eiffel_Tower_at_night

The copyright owners would long since have formally demanded that wikipedia take them down, and they'd be long gone.

In terms of what tour-effel.fr says, Relaxed is right.  Would-be right-holders are generally not to be trusted for information on copyright; they routinely try to claim rights they don't have, and to intimidate people who want to take pictures without any sound legal basis.

It may be that the legal system is corrupt enough for a nonsense decision in a local court to decide otherwise under financial or nationalist pressure, but would a US or other non-French court agree or enforce such a finding?  Very doubtful.

Comment: Nonsense from whose perspective? Why would only US or non-French courts define what is legal or not? If French law is consistent on this then it seems your personal opinion or foreign practice is not a sound basis to call travelot's answer wrong. It might or might not apply to your particular situation and you might also disapprove of it but that's still the law, at least in France. The link you provide does in fact suggest the claim has *some* validity and Wikipedia complied (again, to some extent, i.e. for a special light show, not for all night-time pictures).

Comment: It's a FACT that that there are *STILL* over 300 free photos of the Eiffel Tower here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Eiffel_Tower_at_night  That's not my opinion.

It's well established, mainstream view that would-be rights-holders are generally not to be trusted for information on copyright and that it is common for  would-be rights-holders to try to claim rights they don't have, and to intimidate people who want to take pictures without any sound legal basis.

It's the law in France that the view of the lighted Eiffel Tower is only copyrighted when it has non-standard lighting.

Comment: Why would courts define what is legal or not? 

Umm... because that's their job in a balanced three-branches-of-government system : to interpret the law.  Courts are the highest authority on what is legal or not.

Comment: That's completely beside the point, have you actually read my comment? I certainly did not write anything about “the courts” in general.

Comment: No legal decision has been made in France on the status of images of the Eiffel Tower under the normal nighttime lighting seen in the bulk of the images on commons.  By nonsense, I am referring to a possible ruling if a legal decision on that came before a French court.

"What exactly is allowed" has to be answered with reference to a particular (legal) system or systems.  IN this case, France's is the relevant one.  ...

Comment: @Relaxed, I did not rely on personal opinion or foreign practice.  Perhaps you think I did because you don't know that  commons is committed to only hosting content that is free in the US and in the source country.

For someone named "Relaxed"... act more like it.  Perhaps it's you who needs to read more carefully. 

If you wish to dispute my claim that "It's the law in France that the view of the lighted Eiffel Tower is only copyrighted when it has non-standard lighting," dispute it by presenting evidence.

Comment: As noted on commons, with a reference: "The Société d'exploitation de la tour Eiffel (SETE) states that the various illuminations of the tower are trademarked and claims that they are under copyright, BUT THIS HAS NEVER BEEN PROVED IN A COURT." (my emphasis)

Comment: Your answers mentioned “US or non-French courts”, your next comment merely “the courts” (which is rather unhelpful when the whole point is that there are several legal systems) and now you're telling me that “France's is the relevant one”. That the question “has to be answered with reference to a particular (legal) system” was in fact my point but that's precisely what you failed to do.

Comment: Regarding the distinction between light show and standard lighting, since I wrote as much in my answer long before you wrote yours and again in my comment above, I am not sure why you still pretend that this is what our discussion is about. The problem is that the only thing you added to the existing answers is a lot of confusion (especially in the last paragraph) and that's what I have been commenting about all along.

Comment: This conversation is unproductive and contrary to the spirit of the site.  If you don't like my last paragraph, EDIT IT to make it better!  I don't see the problems you are referring to.  The paragraph is speculative, and could be worded better.

I'm not confusing anything by providing evidence that this sentence is false:

'By night, the eiffel tower lighting is under copyright if it's the main subject of the picture.'

in the form of images of the eiffel tower lighting at night that are NOT under copyright.

French law is that the normal night-time lighting is NOT copyrighted.

Comment: Since I downvoted your answer, I consider it a matter of basic courtesy to explain why. If you improve the answer, I will remove my vote and/or upvote it. That's exactly what comments are for and perfectly in the spirit of the site. OTOH, interpreting travelot's answer so uncharitably while being so imprecise yourself and being incoherent just to win an argument probably isn't.

Comment: Do you speak French? Have you actually seen the light shows they put on the Tour Eiffel? Please don't make up stuff about “image-projecting lighting”, there is no such language in the decision.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a bit rich of you to write an answer that is essentially a rather aggressive criticism of someone else's answer, to discover two months later that you could have edited the original answer (or better yet, commented constructively!) and then to complain about the “spirit of the site” because you can't take criticism yourself…

Comment: By night, the eiffel tower artistic lighting is not necessarily under copyright, even when it's the main subject of the picture.  On the one hand, the Société d'Exploitation de la Tour Eiffel (SETE) claims that the various illuminations of the tower are trademarked, and claims that they are under copyright, but on the other hand, this has been proved in a court only with respect to image-projection lighting, not the normal night-time lighting.
Yes, I speak French and I've seen the lighting.  Please don't make up claims that I've made up claims.  I didn't claim to quote the decision verbatim.